# python assign print output to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings which has below elements. This list can have 1,2, or more elements.

```
list=['abc', 'xyz']
```

I want to use them and create a one line string like below and use it later in some other string concatenations (creating a command):

```
Move abc to folder c:\data, move xyz to folder c:\data
```

Until now I have managed to print them with:

```
for i in list:
  print("Move '" + i + "' to folder 'C:\DATA'",end=", ")
```

output is:

```
Move 'xyz' to folder 'c:\DATA', Move 'xyz' to folder 'c:\DATA',
```

I want to remove  the last comma  and if possible to assign this output to a variable. Finally the scope is to generate and execute a command (using subprocess module) like this:

```
restore database db move 'xyz' to folder 'c:\data', Move 'xyz' to folder 'c:\DATA' -server servername -instance instance_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print something, it's a one-shot thing. The string you made for printing is gone once it's shown on the console<sup>1</sup>. Instead you are probably going to want to build a string with your formatted data in memory, and then print it, or do something else.

String's `join` method will allow you to insert commas only between elements. The `format` method will allow you to format the individual elements with custom data:

```
mystring = ", ".join("Move '{}' to folder 'C:\\DATA'".format(i) for i in mylist)
```

Now you have a string that you can print, concatenate, split, pass to a subprocess, etc...

---

<sup>1</sup> you can print to an in-memory file and extract the output that way, but we won't go into that now.

Comment: thank you very much. it is almost what i wanted, but mystring returns 2 rows. Probably because of looping.

Comment: Could be your console size

Comment: :) - it was from this for i in list:

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via the `join` function in Python.

```
>>> lst = ['abc', 'xyz']
>>> s = ', '.join([r'Move {} to folder c:\data'.format(f) for f in lst])
>>> print(s)
Move abc to folder c:\data, Move xyz to folder c:\data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` for that:

```
list=['abc', 'xyz']
print(", ".join([ "Move '{0}' to folder 'c:\{0}'".format(item) for item in list]))

# Move abc to folder c:\abc, Move xyz to folder c:\xyz
```